# Updating to macOS 13.3 broke compiling cpp

Tags: c++, macos, nullptr

After updating to Ventura 13.3, installing latest Xcode and command line tools, I get this error while compiling any cpp file

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:50:9: error: no member named 'nullptr_t' in the global namespace
```

it happens in `#include <iostream>`

for example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:841:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/copy.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/unwrap_iter.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/iterator_traits.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/incrementable_traits.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/concepts:133:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__concepts/arithmetic.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:421:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional/invoke.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/apply_cv.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/remove_reference.h:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:50:9: error: no member named 'nullptr_t' in the global namespace
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:841:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/copy.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/unwrap_iter.h:13:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/iterator_traits.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__iterator/incrementable_traits.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/concepts:133:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__concepts/arithmetic.h:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:452:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_compound.h:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_fundamental.h:14:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_null_pointer.h:24:49: error: use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_null_pointer.h:24:49: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__type_traits/is_null_pointer.h:23:17: note: template parameter is declared here
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:848:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:45: error: field has incomplete type 'std::exception_ptr'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:144:24: note: definition of 'std::exception_ptr' is not complete until the closing '}'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:5: error: '__abi_tag__' attribute only applies to structs, variables, functions, and namespaces
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:689:37: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:673:26: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI'
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:848:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:94:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:149:55: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:860:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:3: error: non-static data member cannot be constexpr; did you intend to make it const?
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:728:31: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:860:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:32: error: member 'nullptr_t' declared as a template
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:173:42: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:262:25: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:395:3: error: non-static data member cannot be constexpr; did you intend to make it const?
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:728:31: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR'
In file included from Untitled.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:41:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:221:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:18:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:860:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:28:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:395:32: error: member 'nullptr_t' declared as a template
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:395:42: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:484:25: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:14: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:24: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'int' with an rvalue of type 'std::nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:533:24: note: passing argument to parameter here
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:594:45: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:602:12: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/unique_ptr.h:610:45: error: unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

If the above sample code is placed in Test.C, the following command line will cause the errors:

```
clang++ -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -g -c -o Test.o Test.C
```

Comment: IIRC the Apple Clang compiler still defaults to the C++03 standard, and `nullptr` (and the corresponding `nullptr_t` type) were introduced in C++11. Try adding the `-std=c++11` flag when building. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but no, it doesn't. I have used ```-std=c++11``` already

Comment: sorry, compiling

Comment: Make a small example (Hello World is good enough if "any c++ file" is affected), add it to the question, then show your exact command-line and complete compiler output when trying to compile that small example.

Comment: thanks, I have added a hello world example

Comment: The error dump misses the compiler invocation command. Xcode always shows it, but you have decided to skip it.

Comment: Update: in Xcode everything works fine, but when in CodeRunner or VS Code I get this errors

Comment: I had possibly similar issue when installing some software https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib/issues/442#issuecomment-1495688495 I am still on Ventura 13.2.1, was planning to try upgrading to 13.3 in case it would 'un-break' something

Comment: I upgraded to 13.3 and it didn't help. Found a similar looking issue here https://github.com/chipsalliance/verible/issues/260 which they fixed by adding `#include <cstddef>` at the top of their header file and also prefixing `nullptr_t` as `std::nullptr_t`

Comment: I'm having the same issue!  This is very frustrating as it has broken all development on my machine (I don't use Xcode, VS Code or any other IDE, just simple Makefiles and CLI)

Comment: My guess would be that as you've used the extension `.C` it's compiling your code as c where including `iostream` would be invalid. Use a conventional c++ extension like `cpp`, `cc` or `cxx`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks for the suggestion.  Unf. changing the suffix doesn't fix the compile errors.

Comment: This question offers a workaround (downgrading your SDK version) 
 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458062/unable-to-find-include-file-on-newly-updated-macosc-c/459037#459037 Unf. if you're trying to target the latest versions of Ventura (macos 13.3) using SDK 13.3 seems to the only way (per guidelines on this page: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode ) I'm crossing my fingers for a real fix from Apple (and have submitted the issue via the Feedback Reporter tool) but in the mean-time, grateful for the workaround.

Comment: I just asked about this in the developer forums too: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729072

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, [this answer solved it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/459037/494804). In my case, except to `rm -rf MacOSX.sdk`, I had to call also `rm -rf MacOSX13.3.sdk`.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and finally tracked it down to an environment variable that was set in my environment.

The variable is

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

I had previously followed the workaround described here:

https://cmichel.io/fixing-cpp-compilation-bugs-for-the-mac-os-catalina-upgrade/

which involved setting an environment variable (in my bash .profile):

CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/include/c++/v1:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include

**Removing the CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable fixed the problem and compilation works again!!!**

Hopefully this will help someone else get past this tricky/subtle build problem!

If not, "eskimo" on the Apple Developer forums offered some helpful diagnostic suggestions when I posted this issue on the Apple Developer Forum.  Maybe those would be of use.  The URL of the post is:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729072

(Unfortunately you may need to be a registered/logged-in Apple Developer to access that page, but... )  The diagnostic commands he requested I run were the following:

- sw_vers
- xcode-select -p (to show setting)
- xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools (to set setting)
- csrutil status
- pkgutil --pkgs
- printenv | \grep CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH (my own addition)

The results of these commands might be helpful for someone to help you, if you continue to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar issue but none of the solutions posted here have worked. What finally helped was using `zig cc` and `zig c++` to compile the code instead, which avoids the MacOSX SDK standard library and uses its own.

See https://actually.fyi/posts/zig-makes-rust-cross-compilation-just-work/.

`~/.local/bin/zig-cc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
zig cc $@
```

`~/.local/bin/zig-c++`:

```
#!/bin/sh
zig c++ $@
```

and build with `CC=zig-cc CXX=zig-c++ cmake ...`.